# Converting a 2-adic expansion to a fraction

Tags: computer-science, p-adic-number-theory, binary

I've been experimenting with the idea of using 2-adic expansions of numbers to efficiently do division on computers. For instance, if you have the 8-bit integer, 171(0b10101011), multiplied by 3 truncates to 1(in full it's 0b1000000001, which as an 8-bit number simply equals 1), meaning that it's effectively 1/3 in this number system. My question is if there's a way to convert this truncated number back to a fraction without simply multiplying it with every number until you find the one that equals one. Further, if I multiply two of these fractions together, is it possible to determine whether the result is a fraction or a whole number?

Comment: But since you seem to be not actually computing in the $2$-adics but rather in the quotient ring $\mathbb Z/2^8 \mathbb Z$, your questions are not well-defined. As you say yourself, in that ring, the residue class of $171$ equals $1/3$, so "is" that number a whole number, or a fraction? And are you aware that this residue class is also that of $-341$, and of $3073/3$, and of ...?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to compute the inverse without search its multiples. The method is actually well-known, as it effectively the same as inverting in the real numbers, with only a trivial deviation. The result of applying it is what is already implemented by computers for doing division.

Comment: @PaulSinclair That's great! can you explain the method or provide a link? Thanks!

Comment: You didn't learn it in grade school like the rest of us?